# error during installation

Tags: boot, grub2, usb-installation

I was trying to install Ubuntu on my laptop(currently my system have no operating system)
After I partitioned drives and hit install , grub install fatal error rised,
I followed solution on the internet and tried boot repair but then an error occurred during repair with following link :

---

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GtD9QkSzQQ/

I failed to find the solution on the internet , I found one that need an installed operating system which I don`t have .
I hold one of my previous drives that include personal files from windows and don’t change it in partitioning , I doubt maybe it caused the error.

Comment: It looks like you still have a Windows partition on your hard drive. You say that you do not have an operating system, but how did you install Ubuntu? A USB key? A DVD? Some other way? You will likely want to re-install and, when the installer asks about your disk, say "Use entire disk".

Comment: @matigo I formatted windows drive before trying to install Ubuntu , then I tried to install with bootable usb.

Comment: Too many things wrong here to justify the time wasted in fixing it. Do a fresh install instead. Now, before the actual installation open Gparted, select the target drive and then Devices menu > Create new partition table and select "GPT". Now just start the installation and chose the automatic option, "erase and install..." Done!